# Moving from Visual Studio 2017 Pro to Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was using VS 2017 Pro, and the license ran out.  Now using VS 2017 CE.  I have the CE edition working with the AWS code commit, and SSRS package.  Wondering if uninstalling the PRO edition will cause any issues for the CE edition, AWS code commit, or SSRS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely uninstall the PRO edition without changing anything within the CE edition as they are different products and can exist side by side. With that being said, as long as you have the Visual Studio Installer on your machine, you can install any required packages needed that act as an 'update' on top of the CE edition.

I would uninstall the PRO edition via the Visual Studio Installer as it promts at the end if you want to use another version of Visual Studio, backup and settings you may have as that is known to be deleted for some reason.

You can read about backing up settings [here](https://community.submain.com/blogs/howto/archive/2009/05/30/how-to-backup-and-restore-visual-studio-settings.aspx).